# Is it possible to use pyminifier with py2app?

Tags: obfuscation, py2app

I have a python 3.4 app which I want to publish to the app store. I also want to obfuscate the code as much as possible. I found the [pyminifier](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyminifier/2.1) library which seems to be perfect for the job. However, I am not able to figure out how to use it for an app that is packaged using py2app. I am not even sure if that is possible. I am also open to other strategies to obfuscate.

Answer (score 0):

You need declare all imports in the obfuscated file before use py2app

```
import zlib, base64, os, paramiko
exec(zlib.decompress(base64.b64decode('eJyVUl2P..."
```